# YII many to many relationship and composite primary key

Tags: php, sql, yii

I have to tables connected by a third relationship table. However one of the two tables has a composite primary key (see below).
How can I declare the MANY_MANY relationship in a model?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (
id integer,
someOtherID integer,
somevalue text,
PRIMARY KEY(id, someOtherID)
)

CREATE TABLE T2 (
id integer PRIMARY KEY,
value text
)

CREATE TABLE R (
rID1 integer,
rOtherID1 integer,
rID2 integer REFERENCES T2(id),
FOREIGN KEY (rID1, rOtherID1) REFERENCES T1(id, someOtherID),
PRIMARY KEY (rID1, rOtherID1, rID2)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to override `CActiveRecord::primaryKey()` method in your model:

```
//for T1 model
public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('id', 'someOtherID');
}
```

And relation declaration will be:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'T2'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'T2', 'R(rID2, rID1)'),
        ...
    );
}
```

Maybe you will should add condition to relation:

```
'T2'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'T2', 'R(rID2, rID1)', 'condition'=>'R.someOtherID = t.someOtherID'),
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

An intersection table is defined pretty much the same way no matter what kind of key(s) are defined in the primary tables. Define the field(s) of the key for the first table and define that as FK to that table. Define the field(s) of the key for the second table and define that as FK to that table. Then define both sets of fields as composite key of the intersection table.

You have it mostly done in your example:

```
CREATE TABLE R (
  t1_ID integer,
  t1_someOtherID integer,
  t2_ID integer,
  FOREIGN KEY (t1_ID, t1_someOtherID) REFERENCES T1(id, someOtherID),
  foreign key( t2_id ) references T2( id ),
  PRIMARY KEY( t1_ID, t1_someOtherID, t2_ID )
)
```

You may, of course, add other fields as attributes of the relationship itself, such as how many of *these* parts (first table) go into the making of *that* subassembly (second table). But the definition above is a fully functional, if bare minimum, intersection table.